# A additive and convex function is linear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be an additive and convex function. How to prove that $f=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: In particular $b=0$.

Comment: @Jlamprong Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function satisfies $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),\textrm{ and }f(tx+(1-t)y)\le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y),\  \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},t\in[0,1].$$

1. Putting $x=y=0$, you will get $f(0)=0$,
2. Putting $y=-x$ you'll get $f(-x)=-f(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.
3. Putting $y=nx$ and using induction, you'll get $f(nx)=nf(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, for $x=1$ it tells $f(n)=an$ where $a=f(1)$
4. To extend to $\mathbb{Q}$, take any $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, i.e., $x=\frac mn$ for some integers $m,n$. Note that $am=f(m)=f(nx)=nf(x)\iff f(x)=a\frac mn=ax$. So, in this step you'll have $f(x)=ax,\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}.$
5. The last step is extending to $\mathbb{R}$ (It is the most interesting step). Here, the convexity will play his role. Take any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x>0$ since you already knew $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$. If $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $f(x)=ax$, if not, i.e.,  $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$ then there exists rational number $a,b$ such that $a<x<b$. Since $x$ can be written as $x=\frac{b-x}{b-a}a+\frac{x-a}{b-a}b$ with $\frac{b-x}{b-a}+\frac{x-a}{b-a}=1$ then 
   \begin{align}
   f(x)&=f\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}a+\frac{x-a}{b-a}b\right)\le \frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b)=ax.
   \end{align}
   On the other hands, we can also choose $s\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<s<2x$. By writing $s$ as $s=\frac{2x-s}{x}x+\frac{s-x}{x}2x$ with $\frac{2x-s}{x}+\frac{s-x}{x}=1$, you get
   \begin{align}
   as&=f(s)=f\left(\frac{2x-s}{x}x+\frac{s-x}{x}2x\right)\\
   &\le \frac{2x-s}{x}f(x)+\frac{s-x}{x}f(2x)=\frac{2x-s}{x}f(x)+\frac{2s-2x}{x}f(x)\\
   &=\frac sxf(x).
   \end{align}
   Since $x>0$ then $f(x)\ge ax$. Consequently, you will come up with $f(x)=ax$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, as you wanted. Here $a=f(1)$.